# Check if eclipse editor document was changed by another editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, editor

I created a custom eclipse editor (AbstractDecoratedTextEditor) and I need to know when another editor modifies and saves some file opened in editor.

For exemple, I have the document A opened in my custom eclipse editor and I modified and saved this document in another editor, I need to execute some tasks when this occurs.

I tried to use the listener IDocumentListener like that:

```
    final IEditorInput input = editor.getEditorInput();
    IDocumentProvider documentProvider = editor.getDocumentProvider();
    IDocument document = documentProvider.getDocument(input);

    document.addDocumentListener(new IDocumentListener() {
        @Override
        public void documentAboutToBeChanged(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            //Empty
        }

        @Override
        public void documentChanged(DocumentEvent arg0) {
            // Do something HERE
            doTask();
        }
    });
```

But the method documentChanged executes 2 times:

1) When the editor outsie eclipse edit and save the file. (That is I need)

2) When I edit the document with my custom editor without need saving. (That is I dont need)

The problem is the number 2 executes every typed letter. I need the method documentChanged executes only for number 1.

Comment: `documentChanged` is always going to be called for every typed character. You could use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for changes to the input `IFile`.

Comment: To use this listener I tried ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener, but Its fired for each document. How can I fire for only specific document, like document.addResourceChangeListener ?? Thks

Comment: No it will fire for everything while it is active. You can use `IResourceDelta.findMember(path)` to see if it contains your file.

Comment: I get the path using ((FileEditorInput)input).getPath(), this path has 
the exactly path of file, but return null in arg0.getDelta().findMember(path)

Comment: FileEditorPath gives a full path, findMember wants a path relative to the workspace.

Comment: Thanks Greg, I used this commands to get path: IFile file = (IFile) input.getAdapter(IFile.class); IPath path = file.getFullPath(); And It works.